# Converting a list of part numbers into a two-dimensional array of width/length for display in grid

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list of parts with each part consisting of part_number, width and length. I want to end up displaying this list as a grid using the various widths as column labels and the various lengths as row labels.

```
       width1   width2   width3   width4
len1    no1       no2
len2    no3       no4      no5
len3    no6       no7      no8      no9
```

Note that parts are not available in all lengths and widths and that some cells in the grid will be empty.

I began by wrangling all this data into lists. One for column labels, one for row labels and one for data thinking I could use panda to create a DataFrame.

```
columns = []
rows = []
li = []
for part in part_list:
    if part.width not in columns:
        columns.append(part.width)
    if part.length not in rows:
        rows.append(part.length)

    li.append([part.width, part.length, part.part_number])      

    data_dict = {
        'part_number': weld_stud.part_number,
        'diameter_pitch': weld_stud.thread,
        'length': weld_stud.fractional_length
    }

    grid_data.append(data_dict)
```

Then, using panda I did:

```
numpy_array = np.array(li)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=numpy_array[1:,1:],    # values
    index=numpy_array[1:,0],    # 1st column as index
    columns=numpy_array[0,1:]   # 1st row as the column names
)
```

This is obviously not outputting what I need, but I'm unclear where to go from here.

Comment: Can you add an example of your initial dataframe?

Comment: There's some potential issues with what you want. What's supposed to happen if two different parts (with two different part numbers) have the same width and length?

Comment: There would be no duplication of part numbers with the same width and length. Within a class of parts, there can be only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I reedited this answer many times, so I hope this is last time**

Answer is consisted of two things:

1) Data preparation: I dont know your dataset, but I will guess

2) Data display

---

**1) a ) Data preparation**

I know about one easy solution which may solve all your problems with data preparations. But one condition must be met, and that is that your widths and lengths are integers. If this is true, then solution is easy:
lets say max width is 10 and max length is 10 too.

You create grid of 11x11 in numpy (because from 0 to 10 is 11 cells )

```
# chararray because you can initialize
# grid with being empty (empty string fields)
grid=np.chararray(shape=[11,11]) 

for part in part_list:
    grid[part.width,part.length] = str(part.part_number)
    #If you have 2 parts with same parameter you can sum up string so its flexible
```

**So basicly you can use array indexes as actual parameters width and lentgh**

**1) b ) Data preparation**

your problem somehow sticked in my mind until i found general solution to your problem (Even though I still dont know your dataset). **Based on above example**, if your parameters are in any form (int, float, string) you can do this

```
# Lets say you have 3 types of widths and lengths and you index them 
# Key is your parameter, value is index position in grid
widths = {'7.2mm':0,'9.6mm':1,'11.4mm':2}
lengths = {'2.2mm':0,'4.8mm':1,'16.8mm':2}

header = [h for h in widths] # useless in this example
side = [s for s in lengths ] # but can serve for Data display part


grid=np.chararray(shape=[3,3])

for part in part_list:
    index_width = widths[part.width]
    index_lentgh = lengths[part.length]
    grid[index_width ,index_lentgh] = str(part.part_number)

# This way, you dont need to care about missing part numbers and grid can stay unfilled
```

**2) Data display**

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def table(header,side,data):
    t = PrettyTable(['']+header)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        t.add_row([side[i]]+list(data[i]))
    print(t)

header = ['col1','col2','col3']
side =   ['row1','row2','row3']
data =   np.zeros(shape=[3,3])
>> table(header,side,data)

+------+------+------+------+
|      | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+------+
| row1 | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0  |
| row2 | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0  |
| row3 | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

You can feed it with anything(like classes)

```
data2 = [['','',PrettyTable],['World','',5],['','Hello','']]
table(header,side,data)
>>> table(header,side,data2)
+------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+
|      |  col1 |  col2 |                col3               |
+------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+
| row1 |       |       | <class 'prettytable.PrettyTable'> |
| row2 | World |       |                 5                 |
| row3 |       | Hello |                                   |
+------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+
```

EDIT: Based on sample data I was able to  do what was required:

```
import numpy as np
widths = {'#10-24':0, '#10-32':1, '1/4-20':2, '5/16-18':3, '3/8-16':4, '1/2-13':5, '5/8-11':6, '3/4-10':7} # My data dictionary looks like
lenghts = {'5/8':0,'3/4':1,'7/8':2}
part_list = [{'part_number': 'FTC19-62', 'width': '#10-24', 'length': '5/8'},
        {'part_number': 'FTC19-75', 'width': '#10-32', 'length': '3/4'},
        {'part_number': 'FTC19-87', 'width': '#10-24', 'length': '7/8'}]

grid=np.chararray(shape=[len(lenghts),len(widths)]).astype('|S8')
grid[:,:] = ''

for part in part_list:
    index_width = widths[part['width']]
    index_lentgh = lenghts[part['length']]
    grid[index_lentgh,index_width] = str(part['part_number'])

header = sorted(widths, key=lambda k: widths[k])
side = sorted(lenghts, key=lambda k: lenghts[k])
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def table(header,side,data):
    t = PrettyTable(['']+header)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        t.add_row([side[i]]+list(data[i]))
print(t)


table(header,side,grid)


+-----+----------+----------+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     |  #10-24  |  #10-32  | 1/4-20 | 5/16-18 | 3/8-16 | 1/2-13 | 5/8-11 | 3/4-10 |
+-----+----------+----------+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 5/8 | FTC19-62 |          |        |         |        |        |        |        |
| 3/4 |          | FTC19-75 |        |         |        |        |        |        |
| 7/8 | FTC19-87 |          |        |         |        |        |        |        |
+-----+----------+----------+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
>>>
```

Comment: Since my widths and lengths are not integers, I've used your second solution to index all my widths and lengths and then inserted the part numbers into the grid. This seems to work, but I'm unclear how to render this grid onto the web page.

Comment: Between the numpy grid and rendering it into html is quite a lot of steps. If your inital question was answered, we should close it, and you may want to look for topics like Flask, django or other frameworks dealing with web and parsing data as HTML content.

Comment: That makes sense. But looking at the grid, it appears that instead of displaying the part number, the cells show b'F', which looks like only the first character of the part number. Other cells have random things like b'\xea'

Comment: I cant help you with this without seeing the data. Can you provide some sample?

Comment: Sure. Using your suggestion, widths = {'#10-24':0, '#10-32':1, '1/4-20':2, '5/16-18':3, '3/8-16':4, '1/2-13':5, '5/8-11':6, '3/4-10':7} My data dictionary looks like [{'part_number': 'FTC19-62', 'width': '#10-24', 'length': '5/8'}, {'part_number': 'FTC19-75', 'width': '#10-24', 'length': '3/4'}, {'part_number': 'FTC19-87', 'width': '#10-24', 'length': '7/8'}, ...

Comment: Here's what the array partially looks like: chararray([[b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F',b'\x1e', b'\x93'],[b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', '', '',''], [b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', '', ''],,[b'\x06', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F',b'F', b'F', ''],['', '', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F',b'F'],['', '', '', '', '', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F'],['', '', '', '', b'\x01', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F', b'F',b'F']], dtype='|S1')

Comment: I edited the answer. Problem with only one letter was that charr array type was 'S1' -> I higher it to S8 but maybe you need more, the second problem I do not know why it happens ('\x93') but I can get rid of it, by: grid[:,:] = ''